How to pass private key to the JsonWebSignature?
I am using org.bitbucket.b_c:jose4j:0.9.6 and I am trying to sign a JWT token and using below code. I am unable to find a way to pass private key to the JsonWebSignature object.
jws.setKey(PublicJsonWebKey.Factory.newPublicJwk(privateKeyPem).getPrivateKey());

This is the line where I am trying to set the key.
String consumerKey = "****************************************";
String certificateId = "sdsdsdssdsdsdsdssdsdsdsfefer";
String tokenEndpoint = "https://xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/token";

String privateKeyPem = "-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----\n"
    + "MII.......................
      .........................Q3AFte\n "
    + "+**************************s=\n"
    + "-----END PRIVATE KEY-----";

JwtClaims claims = new JwtClaims();
claims.setIssuer(consumerKey);
claims.setAudience(tokenEndpoint);
claims.setExpirationTimeMinutesInTheFuture(60); // 1 hour
claims.setGeneratedJwtId();
claims.setIssuedAtToNow();
claims.setClaim("scope", "restlets rest_webservices");

// Create JWS Header
JsonWebSignature jws = new JsonWebSignature();
jws.setPayload(claims.toJson());
jws.setAlgorithmHeaderValue("PS256");
jws.setKeyIdHeaderValue(certificateId);
jws.setKey(
    PublicJsonWebKey.Factory.newPublicJwk(privateKeyPem).getPrivateKey());
jws.setDoKeyValidation(false);

// Sign the JWT
String jwt = jws.getCompactSerialization();

Java imports:
import org.jose4j.jws.JsonWebSignature; 
import org.jose4j.jwt.JwtClaims; 

Maven dependency:
<!-- mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.bitbucket.b_c/jose4j --> 
<dependency> 
    <groupId>org.bitbucket.b_c</groupId> 
    <artifactId>jose4j</artifactId> 
    <version>0.9.6</version> 
</dependency>


You need to identify where the classes JsonWebSignature and JwtClaims are coming from. In general, you need to identify third-party libraries your are using in any question.

Using below classes:
import org.jose4j.jws.JsonWebSignature;
import org.jose4j.jwt.JwtClaims;
Maven dependency -


org.bitbucket.b_c
jose4j
0.9.6


Thank you for your replies @PresidentJamesK.Polk

@MHegde Please [edit] your question, don't add details like that in the comments.

Since setKey() can handle an RSAPrivateCrtKeyImpl instance  (assuming RSA because of PS256), you can import your PEM key with JCA/JCE as usual:
import java.security.KeyFactory;
import java.security.PrivateKey;
import java.security.spec.PKCS8EncodedKeySpec;
import java.util.Base64;
...
String privateKeyPem = "-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----\n"
    + "MII.......................
      .........................Q3AFte\n "
    + "+**************************s=\n"
    + "-----END PRIVATE KEY-----";
byte[] privateKeyDer = Base64.getDecoder().decode(
        privateKeyPem.replace("-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----", "")
        .replace("-----END PRIVATE KEY-----", "")
        .replace("\n", ""));
PKCS8EncodedKeySpec pkcs8 = new PKCS8EncodedKeySpec(privateKeyDer);
KeyFactory kf = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");
PrivateKey privateKey = kf.generatePrivate(pkcs8);
...
jws.setKey(privateKey);


Since PKCS8EncodedKeySpec requires a DER key, it is more convenient to use the DER encoded key directly:
byte[] privateKeyDer = Base64.getDecoder().decode("MII...s=");


The library also has helper classes, e.g. KeyPairUtil. However, I only found support there for PEM encoded public keys (KeyPairUtil#fromPemEncoded()), but not for private keys.
